# allow HH:MM kind of input in a django DateTimeField instead of long format

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a model like this

```
class Timer(models.Model):
"""Represents a timing system"""

   start_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
   end_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

and a form that takes this as the model

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['slug','author','duration',]
        model = Job
```

Trouble comes in when i want to add some timing info, and by that i mean that i have to enter it in the long format

```
DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS
```

the times will be added in real time on the same day as they happen, so the long format looks like a waste of effort, i would rather do it as

```
HH:MM
```

i cant use model.TimeField because i will calculate a duration between a start time and the end time, and someone may straddle midnight by timing their sleep or who knows what else. 
How would i allow input in HH:MM  and have it as datetimefield (eventualy after some effort)? Id like the code to assume the same date as the current date give HH:MM

Comment: You are probably looking for something like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9954498/django-datefield-and-timefield-to-python-datetime

Comment: Drop the parenthesis in `default=datetime.datetime.now()` and also try to change `format` option of the [DateTimeInput widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput) else [make your own widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/). Sorry but I don't have more time ...

Comment: Example HH:MM:SS widget and field - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13824266/django-custom-widget-to-split-an-integerfield-into-hours-and-seconds-fields-in-a/13825412#13825412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the forms documentation, this is what iv decided to do, since i didn't understand @cclerville's suggestion (maybe django is poor?)
here goes:
in my forms.py

```
class MyDateTimeField(forms.Field):

    def to_python(self, value):
        # Return an empty list if no input was given.
        if not value:
            return []
        import datetime 
        today = datetime.date.today()
        hhmm = value.split(':')
        val= datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time(int(hhmm[0]),int(hhmm[1])))
        return val
```

and the form itself:

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    end_time = MyDateTimeField()
```